# Why won't codeblocks use my project options?

Tags: compilation, codeblocks

I did what's needed, right click on the project name, click build options...
Select append target options to project options (I also tried use project options only).

Thing is, I have a define and some compiler flags set but when it compiles it doesn't show them on the command line.

```
mingw32-g++.exe -L"C:\Documents and Settings\Zirgon\Bureau\GSERVER\projects\miniupnpc" -o ..\..\bin\gserver2.exe obj\Release\adler32.o obj\Release\blocksort.o obj\Release\bz2compress.o obj\Release\bzlib.o obj\Release\CEncryption.o obj\Release\CFileQueue.o obj\Release\CFileSystem.o obj\Release\CLog.o obj\Release\compress.o obj\Release\CPluginManager.o obj\Release\crc32.o obj\Release\crctable.o obj\Release\CSettings.o obj\Release\CSocket.o obj\Release\CString.o obj\Release\CTranslationManager.o obj\Release\CUPNP.o obj\Release\CWordFilter.o obj\Release\decompress.o obj\Release\deflate.o obj\Release\gzclose.o obj\Release\gzlib.o obj\Release\gzread.o obj\Release\gzwrite.o obj\Release\huffman.o obj\Release\infback.o obj\Release\inffast.o obj\Release\inflate.o obj\Release\inftrees.o obj\Release\IUtil.o obj\Release\main.o obj\Release\md5.o obj\Release\randtable.o obj\Release\TAccount.o obj\Release\TLevel.o obj\Release\TLevelBaddy.o obj\Release\TLevelBoardChange.o obj\Release\TLevelChest.o obj\Release\TLevelHorse.o obj\Release\TLevelItem.o obj\Release\TLevelLink.o obj\Release\TLevelSign.o obj\Release\TMap.o obj\Release\TNPC.o obj\Release\TPlayer.o obj\Release\TPlayerLogin.o obj\Release\TPlayerNC.o obj\Release\TPlayerProps.o obj\Release\TPlayerRC.o obj\Release\trees.o obj\Release\TServer.o obj\Release\TServerList.o obj\Release\TWeapon.o obj\Release\uncompr.o obj\Release\zutil.o    -lws2_32 -lIphlpapi
```

There should be -O3, -g and -DNO_BOOST in there.

Answer (score 1):

You have most likely messed up your project settings. Try re-creating the project file but this time do not adjust the way the options are handled. If it still messes up then re-install codeblocks!

By default you get Release and Debug. Make sure the command line you are checking is the correct one. Are you setting the options on release and then going for a debug build?

Comment: Not that surprising. Codeblocks is mostly good but from time to time things can go out of sync. It does have a lot of variables to manage. Another thing to note is with your include libs/ If you ever get funny linker errors try changing the order of your libs in the project settings and that can fix it.

Comment: it seems to compile with these options without showing the in the command line... could that be?

Comment: Not sure. Where you are getting the cmd line from? If from some options form then it is probably not correct. A good way to test is to try something like putting a define. Then test the define is there. If so then yes. Which means my theory is incorrect and the Codeblocks is not at fault. Not sure.

Comment: Well, if it compiles the no problem! Maybe the build log is a quick simple derived version or maybe it passes the arguments via a pipe and only shows some of the arguments? Not sure. But if it is working then it does not really matter.